# Serialization of dotnumerics matrix in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, serialization, matrix

I have a class which contains multiple dotnumeric matrices. The matrices contains doubles with a known maximum precision. Each matrix must be saved to a single field in a mssql database.

What is the best practice for doing this?

Since the matrices are dotnumerics classes I do not have control over these, ie. i can't make them implement ISerializable for instance so I guess I have to manually convert the matrices to a string which can be saved, or is there any better solution?

It is more crucial that the conversion is fast than memory efficient.

I'm using EntityFramework as ORM.

Answer (score 0):

You could add behaviour to the dotnumerics either via an extension method or create a derived class with additional functionality (if the dotnumeric matrices are not sealed).
Most likely you will need to serialize it either via `Binary serializer/protobuf.net` or with a own implementation into a byte array.

Comment: The dotnumerics matrix class is sealed unfortunately.

Comment: So you have to use extension methods.